# Mechanized data extraction and text recognition from pdfs

Tags: pdf, computer-vision, ocr

I have some highly structured pdf files which are scanned copies of some historic technical records that I have. There are about a couple thousand pages (about 2K pages) involved and I am attempting to extract the information involved automatically.

The link below contains an image that I found on google. I do not own the image but for illustrative purposes, I am trying to extract information that is housed in a structured "block" similar to this and doing stuff with the extracted information programatically. 
[image]

All text are printed/type-written texts, which should give a good accuracy theoretically. I am willing to learn as needed to make this work, but I am not sure where to start. I would like to know

1. Is there a paid program out there that actually does this automatically?
2. Is there an easy way I can simply program this myself by using certain openly available code library for text recognition and etc? I know of a lot of different OCR tools, but I just don't know how to use them programatically to extract things from something that is enclosed in a block like this (and the block can vary in location since it was scanned)
3. If I need to hire someone to do this, what would be a realistic amount of effort that one would need to put in to generate a script that would achieve this?

This is a one time exercise, meaning that it is making things "pretty" and "dumb-proof" (i.e. GUI not needed) is not important.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible using a combination of two tools. iText and Tesseract OCR.
pseudo-code:

1. implement IEventListener (an iText interface), this interface gets called every time a piece of information (text, line, image) is processed.
2. Separate out the ImageRenderInfo events (these events are responsible for drawing an image on a page)
3. Feed each image to Tesseract (or to be precise, the java wrapper, tess4j)
4. Retrieve the content as text, and (using iText) put the content back in the pdf document. iText allows you low-level access to the document. Thus allowing you to place an arbitrary string at a precise location.
5. Now either process the (enhanced) pdf document using the iText core libraries
6. OR process the (enhanced) pdf document using pdf2Data, an iText add-on that was designed specifically for handling the case of matching documents against templates and retrieving the contents. (turning them into XML)

Useful links:
http://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdf2Data
http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Let me check out PDF2Data. I initially was a little lost on how to convert specific fields in a set format to be extracted accurately. Sounds like that may be the way to go.